# How to enable icons in menus in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, icons, menu

In previous Ububtu releases I could enable icons in menus via several tweak tools, or via the gnome config editor.

All of these options have disappeared or have no effect in 14.04.

Takes me 20 times longer to find the menu item I want now, rather than the previous split-second to spot the colourful icon. :)

Answer (score 8):

To enable menu icons, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true
```

To enable button icons, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons true
```

Source: [Ubuntu unity menu button have icons](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/ubuntu-unity-menu-button-have-icons/)

Edit: You will probably have to log out and back in for the settings to apply.

Comment: Works like a charm! The setting reads 'buttons-...' instead of 'button-...'.