# Why are all button and menu icons gone?

Tags: gnome, icons, gui, gtk3

Using Ubuntu 20.04 I found that - opposed to some other distributions - none of the menu icons or buttons icons are shown.
Is this another "tweak" of the Gnome team?
There has been a discussion [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/02/missing-menu-icons-what-are-gnome-playing-at), it seems that people who can't read very well are getting a hard time.

Example:
Non Ubuntu distro:

[image]

Ubuntu:
-I was not able to take a screenshot with a pulled down menu on Ubuntu - I've used a tool from the guest system:

[image]

My questions are - and I could not find an answer in this forum:

- Is it true, that you can't set any icons for menus and buttons anymore?
- What is the reason behind this?

I've tried to set "menu_have_icons" in dconf to no avail, same with the buttons.

Is there any way to enable that feature for disabled persons?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464146/how-to-enable-icons-in-menus-in-ubuntu-14-04) possible duplicate does not work, since it is the CLI interface for dconf, which I used in vain to enable the icons

**Update**

Just found out that Ubuntu derived "Linux Mint 20" has the scheme "org.cinnamon.desktop.interface/menu_have_icons" that seems to work. The same applies to the buttons...

It boils down to this:
Some users are aware of [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252987/gimp-2-10-20-snap-install-has-no-icons-in-the-menus) or [that problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311212/nemo-file-manager-context-menu-actions) and some aren't.

Gimp is [disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252987/gimp-2-10-20-snap-install-has-no-icons-in-the-menus) as well

(Continuing to select voices that think this approach is ... strange)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable icons in menus in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464146/how-to-enable-icons-in-menus-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: No, because I've tried that (with dconf-editor). It does not work, aka it seemed to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found out:
Since GTK-3.10 the gsettings scheme `org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons` is not valid any more.

Instead the following command can "reactivate" icons for menus and buttons:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
```

Comment: Same issue for me as described by OP. Unfortunately the override is ignored in my case. Any ideas..? To be more specific: This enables icons for some applications (like gimp), but not for others (like nautilus). I am really scratching my head here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the question from the title, it is a decision of the GNOME Team to remove icons in menus. Moreover they don't seem to support an option to enable the icons.

You can find explanation of the decision in this discussion:
https://discourse.gnome.org/t/principle-of-icons-in-menus/4803

Comment: Yes, since the Gnome Team has deviated from sane desktop standards, reducing the ability to configure features, I have switched desktop. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you disabled icons in menus. Type `dconf reset -f / && reboot` to fix it or use `gnome-tweaks`

CAUTION: The first command I mentioned resets EVERYTHING back to default values!

Comment: Good you at least provided a warning, but this is a dangerous command where you reset everything. To solve a single problem, you reset the whole system.

Comment: Well at least it's not as bad as `rm -rf /`
^ DO NOT RUN THAT

Comment: It it a fresh setup and I did NOT disable the menus (nor the buttons). Instead I tried to enable them as described above

Comment: @Arbiter - first thing I did was looking at `gnome-tweaks`- there is no option for setting the icons. So I'll regard your answer as not investigated.